# SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH and START WITH/CONNECT BY PostgreSQL Equivalent

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a query that is part of a much larger query written in Oracle that I need to convert to PostgreSQL.

```
/*rn and cnt are defined earlier*/
SELECT wtn, LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(RESP_TCSI, ','),',') TCSI_CODES
FROM DATA
WHERE rn = cnt
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rn = rn-1
AND PRIOR WTN = WTN
```

From what I'm able to tell, there's not an equivalent to `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH()` in Postgres. I know that Postgres has a `CONNECTBY()` function in tablefunc, but I don't think it does what either the start with and connect by bits do. I'm also aware of what the Postgres equivalent to `LTRIM()` is, but if I have to use `CONNECTBY()` or something similar, I'm not sure if trimming the string is important.

Reading and searching around I noticed that there is probably a way to do this with some recursive select, but I'm unsure how I would do that, and beyond that, I don't really understand what the code is doing. My assumption would be that it has something to do with a hierarchical tree, based on the Oracle equivalents, but even then I'm not sure. How would I do something equivalent or similar to this in Postgres?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [recursive common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
with recursive tree as (
  select wtn, 
         resp_tcsi as tcsi_codes
   from data
   where rn = 1 -- this is the "start with" part

   union all

   select ch.wtn, 
          p.tcsi_codes||','||ch.resp_tcsi 
   from data as ch
    join tree p 
      on ch.rn -1 = p.rn -- this is the "connect by" part
     and ch.wtn = p.wtn
)
select *
from tree;
```

Comment: Sweet, I'll try this out. Thanks.

Comment: The `select` subquery in my post is part of a `with..select` query. Am I able to place another `with` in place of the `select` portion of the `with..select` query? (As in, `with..with..select`)

Comment: @BJ: just stack them `with recursive your_cte as ( ...), tree as (...) select ...`