# How to convert this code from Oracle to Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I am having problem with the conversion of sys_connect_by_path. Start with and connect by are also the problems too. I am trying to get email address of employee using employeecode.

```
select substr (sys_connect_by_path (email , ', '), 2) into v_email_address
      from (select email , row_numeric () over (order by email ) rn,
                   count (*) over () cnt
              from employee 
              where employeecode in (              
                                        select unnest(string_to_array(v_spacefreeempcode,','))as employeecode             
                                     ) 
              and email is not null
           )mak
     where rn = cnt
  start with rn = 1
  connect by rn = prior rn + 1;
```

I have done like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478176/sys-connect-by-path-and-start-with-connect-by-postgresql-equivalent/49125377#49125377) down below but showing me an error
ERROR: 42703: column p.rn does not exist, can you tell me what did I do wrong?

```
  with recursive tree as (
  select 
         email 
   from (select email , row_number () over (order by email ) rn,
                   count (*) over () cnt
              from employee 
              where employeecode in (              
                                        select unnest(string_to_array(v_spacefreeempcode,','))as employeecode             
                                     ) 
              and email is not null
           )mak
   where rn = 1 -- this is the "start with" part

   union all

   select  
          p.email||','||ch.email 
   from (select email , row_number () over (order by email ) rn,
                   count (*) over () cnt
              from employee 
              where employeecode in (              
                                        select unnest(string_to_array(v_spacefreeempcode,','))as employeecode             
                                     ) 
              and email is not null
           ) as ch
    join tree p 
      on ch.rn +1 = p.rn -- this is the "connect by" part

     )select * into mak_email from tree;
     select substr (mak_email, 2) into v_email_address;
```

I am attaching the oracle function I used here.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADDRESS(p_EmployeeCode VARCHAR)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
v_SpaceFreeEmpCode  VARCHAR2(1000); 
v_Email_Address     VARCHAR2(1000); 

BEGIN


   v_SpaceFreeEmpCode := REPLACE(p_EmployeeCode,' ','');

   SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (EMAIL , ', '), 2) INTO v_Email_Address
      FROM (SELECT EMAIL , Row_Number () OVER (ORDER BY EMAIL ) rn,
                   COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
              FROM EMPLOYEE 
              WHERE EmployeeCode in (              
                                        SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_SpaceFreeEmpCode, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) AS EmployeeCode FROM DUAL
                                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT LENGTH (REPLACE (v_SpaceFreeEmpCode, ',', NULL)) FROM DUAL )              
                                     ) 
              AND EMAIL IS NOT NULL
           )
     WHERE rn = cnt
  START WITH rn = 1
  CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1; 


    RETURN v_Email_Address;    
END GET_EMPLOYEE_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
```

Comment: Rather than showing us the code that doesn't work, it's better to explain the _problem_ you are trying to solve. To do that, please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please help me?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention,i converted connect by level of oracle by using string_to_array() or unnest(). I have edited and given the oracle function,please check it again,it;s the last one .Thank you

Comment: Again: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data.